# How to remove the default client side error message in strus2?

Tags: java, css, jakarta-ee, struts2

Any Idea how to remove the error below? It is from my validation.xml. It is already redundant for me... Thank you.

```
    Username must not be blanks
    Password must not be blanks

Username must not be blanks ---> How to remove this?
UserName:   
Password must not be blanks ---> How to remove this?
Password:
```

Actually what i want to do is the error message to be on the right side of the field.

```
UserName: ___________________  * Username must not be blanks
Password:____________________  * Password must not be blanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **simple** template for your form.

```
<s:form theme="simple" ...>
```

And then use the `<s:fielderror>` tag for put your field errors wherever you want.

```
<s:form ...>
    <s:textfield key="field1"> 
    <s:fielderror>
         <s:param>field1</s:param>
    </s:fielderror>
    ...
</s:form>
```

Then you only have to play with CSS to achieve that layout.

**EDIT:** It seems that if you put `<s:fielderror>` your field errors will be in a list. You have two options, edit the template `fielderror.ftl` that it's inside the `struts2.jar` or access to the specific error with `<s:property>` like this:

```
<s:property value="fieldErrors.get('field1').get(0)" />
```

This code will only extract the first validation error of the field.

Comment: simple them is like doing a normal html?

Comment: @toksis The simple theme renders "bare bones" HTML elements. For example, the textfield tag renders the HTML `<input/>` tag without a label, validation, error reporting, or any other formatting or functionality.

Comment: @Piguiras I have a problem with the 
<s:fielderror>
         <s:param>field1</s:param>
</s:fielderror>

I place two of the above for username and password. however the field errors becoms a list..... even thought i place it on <td>username</td> <td> <s:fielderror> (etc) </td>

Comment: @toksis I didn't realise of that. I'm going to edit the question with how you can avoid the field errors becoming a list.

Comment: AWESOME!!!  I had used this one. 
<s:property value="fieldErrors.get('field1').get(0)" /> 
It is working now hehehehe. Just wondering though if like there are lots of error for the specific field, .get(0) will only get the first error assuming that it is like an array index = 0.

Comment: @toksis I didn't test it, but I think that if you iterate over `fieldError.get('field1')` with `<s:iterator>` should do the trick.